# MyProgrammingLab Triangular Number probelm

Tags: python

The question is:

A triangular number is a number that is the sum of the integers from 1 to some integer n. Thus 1 is a triangular number because it's the sum of the integers from 1 to 1; 6 is a triangular number because it's 1+2+3=6.

Given the non-negative integers m and n (with m < n), create a list of the triangular numbers between (and including) m and n. Thus if m is 3 and n is 20, the list would be: [3, 6, 10, 15]. Associate the list with the variable triangulars.

The code I've tried:

```
Sum = 0
triangulars = []
for i in range(m,m+n):
    if (n >= m) and (m >= 0):
         Sum += 1
         triangulars.append(Sum)
```

The error I have is the programming lab recommends I use the sum function, and the results I am getting are no triangular numbers (I should get 6, 10 , 15 when m = 5 and n = 17, instead I get 5, 11, 18 and so on)

Answer (score 1):

I changed it around a bit, put it in a function, renamed some variables, and threw in the test cases of m=3,n=20.  I also tested several other combos including m=5,n=17.  I also employed the sum() function you mentioned that you were asked to use.  Here's the working code:

```
def triangulars(m,n):
    if (n >= m) and (m >= 0):
        sum_list = []
        triangular_list = []
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            sum_list.append(i)
            a_triangular = sum(sum_list)
            if m <= a_triangular <= n:
                print(m,n,a_triangular)
                triangular_list.append(a_triangular)
        print(m,n,triangular_list)
    else:
        print('Invalid m,n values')

m = 3
n = 20
triangulars(m,n)
```

Comment: You can break out of the loop once the sum is `> n`, as this will also be true for all subsequent sums.